# How do I use pandas to count the number of times a name and type occur together within a 60 period from the first instance?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is this:

```
Date        Name      Type           Description   Number
2020-07-24  John Doe  Type1          NaN           NaN      
2020-08-10  Jo Doehn  Type1          NaN           NaN     
2020-08-15  John Doe  Type1          NaN           NaN      
2020-09-10  John Doe  Type2          NaN           NaN  
2020-11-24  John Doe  Type1          NaN           NaN
```

I want the Number column to have the instance number with the 60 day period. So for entry 1, the Number should just be 1 since it's the first instance - same with entry 2 since it's a different name. Entry 3 however, should have 2 in the Number column since it's the second instance of John Doe and Type 1 in the 60 day period starting 7/24 (the first instance date). Entry 4 would be 1 as well since the Type is different. Entry 5 would also be 1 since it's outside the 60 day period from 7/24. However, any entries after this with John Doe, Type 1 would have a new 60 day period starting 11/24.

Sorry, I know this is a pretty loaded question with a lot of aspects to it, but I'm trying to get up to speed on dataframes again and I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point, you could create a pivot table.  (The assign statement just creates a temporary column of ones, to support counting.)  In the example below, each row is a date, and each column is a (name, type) pair.

Then, use the resample function (to get one row for every calendar day), and the rolling function (to sum the numbers in the 60-day window).

```
x = (df.assign(temp = 1)
       .pivot_table(index='date', 
                    columns=['name', 'type'], 
                    values='temp', 
                    aggfunc='count', 
                    fill_value=0)
    )

x.resample('1d').count().rolling(60).sum()
```

Can you post sample data in text format (for copy/paste)?